# Simple Multithread method in java. Is this correct?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have built a multithread process for my test automation in java. The process has to execute the first command which allows to execute the second command. The code works but I know that there is a better way to do it ( 1 of 5 will fail because the second command is executed before first one). Can someone have a look at it and help me a bit? I have built the multithread the last time at college.

```
public static void addRestfulAPIToSupport() throws Exception
    {   
    try{
    //This is the point where i have to use multithread
    //add slave - multithread part
            fifth obj5 = new fifth();
            obj5.start();

            sixth obj6 = new sixth();
            obj6.start();

            Thread.sleep(60000);// i leave to sleep it for 1 min
            //code continues here

    }catch(Exception e)
        log.log(e.getMessage());
    }

}
//class fifth and sixth for my restful api test - adding slave 1 to the cluster
class fifth extends Thread
{
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public void runMultiThread3()
    {
        String slave1 = "172.xx.x.xx";
        String shared = "172.xx.x.xxx";
        String user = "xxx";
        String pass = "xxxxxx";
        log.log("Thread join cluster for slave 1 of ip " + slave1);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();         
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                driver.get("https://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + slave1 + "/access/cluster/joincluster");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException i)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(sixth.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, i);
        }

    }

    public void run()
    {
        runMultiThread3();
    }
}

class sixth extends Thread
{
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public void runMultiThread3()
    {
        String shared = "172.xx.x.xxx";
        String slave1 = "172.xx.x.xx";
        String user = "xxx";
        String pass = "xxxxxx";
        log.log("Thread add node to the cluster for slave 1 of ip " + slave1);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
        try
        {
            driver.get("https://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + shared + "/access/cluster/addnode?address=" + slave1);


            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                driver.get("https://" + user + ":" + pass + "@" + shared + "/access/cluster/addnode?address=" + slave1);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException i)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(fifth.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, i);
        }

    }

    public void run()
    {
        runMultiThread3();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but it sounds like you want the threads to execute one after another, which kind of defeats the purpose of using threads in the first place (threads = parallel execution).  If you really want to serialize the code execution, maybe you don't need to use threads at all.

Comment: If you learn not to use `static` variable for something which is actually local to a single method, you don’t need to create multiple classes containing exactly the same code, you may just create multiple instances of one class. Besides that, sstan already nailed it, if you want serial execution, don’t use threads. Further, as a rule of thump, you can actually count how broken your code is by counting the number of occurrences of `sleep` calls in your code…

Comment: Independent of the conceptual problem (threads for sequential code?), you really should post on the codereview SE site. There are a ton of bad practices in that code from unnecessary code duplication, to extending Thread, to single iteration for loops, naming conventions, ...

Comment: I could not use a sleep between these methods. The methods are Join and Add node to the cluster. Join waits 45 sec till node can be added. The problem is that the command Join does not respond until the timeout is complete. When I tried to continue then with Add node to the cluster I failed because node was not in the proper node's format ( it is only during lifetime of the Join ).

Comment: If I use single thread process with sleep between Join and Add it solve nothing. I have used this "multithread" which execute processes join and add. But I think there is no guarantee that process join is executed as the first one ( or am i wrong?). Also I am not really clear how to extended the sleep time in multithread processes between join and add. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible. I would like to see how I could build it better ( I am not a professional but a college graduate). I hope this does make a sense for you guys, Thanks